# Cannot import ReactiveFormsModule

Tags: angular

When importing ReactiveFormsModule in app.module.ts I get error:

```
compiler.js:2427 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
No provider for ControlContainer ("<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      [ERROR ->]<form class="col s12" id="reg-form">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col "): ng:///AppModule/LoginComponent.html@2:6
.
.
.
```

Anyone has idea what is causing it? It's probably problem with the module, because when I remove all HTML i still get it, and I imported it like in documentation. When I remove import app works with no errors.

Comment: Show exactly how you are importing the module in AppModule

Comment: Are you write import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms'; and @NgModule({  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule,...],...) in your appModule?

Answer (score 0):

This is import, without arrows of course:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
-> import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { SidenavComponent } from './components/sidenav/sidenav.component';
import { MyworksheetsComponent } from './components/myworksheets/myworksheets.component';
import { AddworksheetComponent } from './components/addworksheet/addworksheet.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './components/profile/profile.component';

import { ValidateService } from './services/validate/validate.service';
import { UserService } from './services/user/user.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    SidenavComponent,
    MyworksheetsComponent,
    AddworksheetComponent,
    ProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    -> ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ValidateService,
    UserService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I created new test-app and it works, so it's not problem in module or how im importing it.

Comment: check your loginComponent, can happens you put formGroupName in a div (not in a input), or unclosed some tag or quotes or...

Comment: I removed all HTML from that file and it still breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the directive to any form that is created in all components.html
Example:

```
<form [formGroup]=""> </form>
```

By doing that, the error is eliminated.

Comment: This is kinda old, but I remember that even when there was no HTML error was still there. I think reinstalling all npm modules solved the problem.